# Android Maven project in IntelliJ 14.1.2 unable to resolve appcompat v7 classes

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven Android project with traditional pom.xml which I open in IntelliJ 14.1.2. I have installed the maven repositories for android using the [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/simpligility/maven-android-sdk-deployer) helper utility. IntelliJ successfully resolves the dependencies:

[image: Successfully resolved maven deps from the Maven view]

Yet, my solution does not build nor does the IDE detect v4 or v7 appcompat classes:

```
Error:(9, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(7, 30) java: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
```

[image: IDEA issue]

What am I missing?

This is my [complete pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/sydBwSqL)

**edit**:
To **reproduce** please clone and attempt compilation of [this github project](https://github.com/Nilzor/temp-idea-aar-bug).

I've also posted an issue the to [IntellIJ issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139878) regarding this issue

**edit 2**
I got it to work on my job computer by using some `apklib` artifacts I had lying about in my maven repo folder. Don't know how they got there, so that's kindof a problem. Also .apklib is deprecated afaik.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>22.1.1</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
    <version>22.1.1</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**edit 3**

settings.xml for maven:

```
<settings>
 <profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>myprofile</id>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>android-sdk-repo</id>
         <name>Android SDK repo</name>
         <url>file:///D:\coding\android-sdk\extras\google\m2repository</url>
       </repository>  
       <repository>
        <id>android-sdk-repo2</id>
         <name>Android SDK repo2</name>
         <url>file:///D:\coding\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository</url>
       </repository>     
       <repository>
         <id>default</id>
         <name>Default</name>
         <url>file:///C:\Users\Frode\.m2\repository</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
 </profiles>

 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

output of `dir D:\coding\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository /s` :  http://pastebin.com/0WzZwMGT

output of `dir C:\Users\Frode\.m2\repository\com\android /s` :
http://pastebin.com/Pznha22J

output of `mvn install` from the maven-android-sdk-deployer: http://pastebin.com/RX8qdx4N (fails beacuse well.. it tries to install some API v15 stuff, and I don't have that installed )

output of `mvn install -P 5.0` from the maven-android-sdk-deployer: http://pastebin.com/szyMvNXM (succeeds)

v21 / Android 5.0 is the latest SDK I have installed

Comment: Try with AppCompatActivity

Comment: Doesn't work either.http://imgur.com/FcftmO3 . No classes from the v4 or v7 namespace are resolved at all. It is as if I hadn't added the dependencies to the pom.xml file

Comment: Why do you not just use `Gradle`?

Comment: When people ask Java question on SO do you ask them why not just use C#?

Comment: `Java` and `C#` are totally different things. But `Gradle` and `Maven` are relatives.

Comment: @Nilzor Hi, Are you able to install the project through command prompt? And also, just to make sure, could you post the `settings.xml` that maven use? And could you also tell us how you install the `maven-android-sdk-deployer`?

Comment: @kucing_terbang : I've given you the info you've asked for in edit 2. I'm not sure what you mean with "install the project through command line" - I'm not that familiar with maven from the command line, but `mvn test` failed even worse than in the IDE ("package android.os does not exist")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing few elements in your pom:

- `<packaging>apk</packaging>`
- declaration of `android-maven-plugin`
- dependency to android package

See full pom.xml:

```
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>22.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>aar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
            <version>22.1.1</version>
            <type>aar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
                    <artifactId>support-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1_r2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>21</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: getting closer. Now the only thing not compiling is the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat"`. Any tip for that?

Comment: ah.. it had to be `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat` simply. Now it works - thanks! :-)